# OpenEJB 4.5.1: NameNotFoundException

Tags: ejb-3.1, openejb, initial-context

Its the first time I used the OpenEJB container system. When I use the lockup-Method of the InitialContext, I get a NameNotFoundException. I've read lots of examples and tutorials and in every example the lookup method looks like:

```java
initialContext.lookup("NameOfBean");
```

Now I've found another solution which uses the lookup like the following code snippet which works for me too.

```java
initialContext.lookup("java:global/classpath.ear/ProjectName/NameofBean");
```

The question is why the first version doesn't work for me and what I've done wrong?

Excerpts of the OpenEJB log:

```
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - OpenEJB http://openejb.apache.org/
INFO - Startup: Sat Dec 22 13:17:59 CET 2012
INFO - Copyright 1999-2012 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
INFO - Version: 4.5.1
INFO - Build date: 20121209
INFO - Build time: 08:47
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - openejb.home = D:\workspace\ProjectName
INFO - openejb.base = D:\workspace\ProjectName
INFO - Succeeded in installing singleton service
INFO - Cannot find the configuration file [conf/openejb.xml].  Will attempt to create  one for the beans deployed.
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Default Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath.include=.*'
INFO - Found EjbModule in classpath: D:\workspace\ProjectName\build\classes
INFO - Searched 17 classpath urls in 2184 milliseconds.  Average 128 milliseconds per url.
INFO - Beginning load: D:\workspace\ProjectName\build\classes
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: D:\workspace\ProjectName\classpath.ear
WARNUNG - Method 'lookup' is not available for 'javax.annotation.Resource'. Probably using an older Runtime.
INFO - Auto-deploying ejb NameOfBean: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=NameOfBean)
[... AUTHORS'S NOTE: SOME MORE BEANS]
INFO - Assembling app: D:\workspace\ProjectName\classpath.ear
INFO - Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
INFO - Ignoring XML configuration.
JAVA AGENT NOT INSTALLED. The JPA Persistence Provider requested installation of a ClassFileTransformer which requires a JavaAgent.  See http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/javaagent.html
INFO - OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
INFO - Jndi(name=NameOfBeanRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=NameofBean)
INFO - Jndi(name=global/classpath.ear/ProjectName/NameOfBean!de.mypath.stateless.NameOfBeanInterface) --> Ejb(deployment-id=NameofBean)
INFO - Jndi(name=global/classpath.ear/ProjectName/NameofBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=NameOfBean)
[... AUTHORS'S NOTE: SOME FOR OTHER BEANS]
INFO - OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
INFO - All injection points are validated successfully.
INFO - OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 250 ms.
INFO - Created Ejb(deployment-id=NameOfBean, ejb-name=NameOfBean, container=Default Stateless Container)
[... AUTHORS'S NOTE: SOME FOR OTHER BEANS]
INFO - Quartz scheduler 'OpenEJB-TimerService-Scheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
INFO - Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.6
INFO - Scheduler OpenEJB-TimerService-Scheduler_$_OpenEJB started.
INFO - Started Ejb(deployment-id=NameOfBean, ejb-name=NameOfBean, container=Default Stateless Container)
[... AUTHORS'S NOTE: SOME FOR OTHER BEANS]
```

This is my TestClass:

```java
public class NamerOfBeanOpenEJBTest {

private static InitialContext initialContext;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
       properties.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath.include", ".*");
               initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
}
@Test
public void testBean() throws NamingException{  
    Object object = initialContext.lookup("java:global/classpath.ear/ProjectName/NameOfBean");
    assertNotNull(object);
    assertTrue(object instanceof NameOfBean);
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
    if (initialContext != null) {
        initialContext.close();
    }}
}
```

Does someone have tipps or solutions for me?
Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**

In JBoss AS 7.1 the lookup can places like this example:

```java
new InitialContext().lookup("ejb:/ProjectName//NameOfBean!de." + "mypath.sessionbean.stateless.NameOfBeanInterface");
```

Isnt that possible in OpenEJB? Do I have to change every lookup call in every bean to have a local test with OpenEJB? That wouldn't be really effective and time-saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The strukture of the lookup is {deploymentId}{interfaceType.annotationName}. Therefore in my case it must be

```
initialContext.lookup("NameOfBeanLocal");
```

or
    initialContext.lookup("NameOfBeanRemote");
depending on the type of the interface.

To get the problem with JBoss solved you can switch from default lookup

```
new InitialContext().lookup("ejb:/ProjectName//NameOfBean!de." + "mypath.sessionbean.stateless.NameOfBeanInterface");
```

to something more flexible like Dependcy-Lookup or Dependency-Injection and use the @EJB annotation. Both ways are supportet by JBoss and OpenEJB.